# How to route to another port with Zuul

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am trying to route all of my microservices to one route with the port 8080 (shop)

I have a microservice **articlemicroservice** that is connected to an Eureka Server (port:8084).

I do also have **zuulservice** connected to Eureka (running on Port 8888).

Example:
http://localhost:8084/articles should be available on http://localhost:8080/articles

I tried to configure it in my application.yml in my zuul server like this:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8888/eureka
server:
  port: 8079
zuul:
  routes:
    articlemicroservice:
      path: /*
      serviceId: articlemicroservice
      url: http://localhost:8080/
```

**Important:** Shop (Port:8080) is not connected to Eureka.

**ArticleMicroService:**

```
server.port=8084
spring.application.name=articlemicroservice

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8888/eureka/
eureka.client.fetchRegristry=true
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
```

**ShopMicroService:**

```
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=shopmicroservice
```

**Edit:** The example with the yml did not work.

**Edit:**

**Eureka Server:**

```
server.port=8888
spring.application.name=eurekaserver

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8888/eureka/

eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds:2
```

Comment: I think you have some concepts messed up. The only thing that can forward to something else is zuul running on port 8079. It can forward traffic to port 8080.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need one GatewayApplication on port 8080, this application will proxy requests for other applications deployed under any other ports

1. Run Zuulproxy on 8080
2. Run ShopMicroService on ex. 8081
3. Run ArticleMicroService on 8084
4. Configure zuul routes like:

   ```
   zuul:
     routes:
       articlemicroservice:
           path: /article/**
           url: http://localhost:8084/
       shopmicroservice:
           path: /shop/**
           url: http://localhost:8081/
   ```

awesome example : https://github.com/sqshq/piggymetrics

OR I think you can @EnableZuulProxy in ShopMicroService

```
zuul:
  routes:
    articlemicroservice:
      path: /article/**
      url: http://localhost:8084/
```

I don't think there is a way to make ZUUL works on 8079